# Adding different style to a series in legend in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

can I somehow add a different style to a legend series? or make it display a gradient square instead of white space?

For example look at fiddle below:

```
chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        color: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 500],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(100, 100, 155)']
            ]
        }
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wXqM9/

As you can see the line is a gradient type and it is okay, but the series is white instead of gray gradient, I can't figure it out why is it in that way. Thanks.

Comment: This really seems not to be possible to change by some setting. I suppose the only hack without changing the code would be to set some Javascript to change the color in the legend

Comment: Okay, sorry, but I'm not too familiar with highcharts API to make  hacks for that, I suppose is made using formatter: function(){}, but I don't know how to read and insert data in legend so that I can choose whatever style I want.

Comment: The formatter function only formats the label (=text), and i have not found an option to change the color of the color mark in the legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are two ways of defining gradient in Highcharts. One in pixels, like you did, and second is percent (scale: 0-1), when setting `linearGradient` as object. Here is a second example: http://jsfiddle.net/wXqM9/10/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        color: {
            linearGradient: {x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1},
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(100, 100, 155)']
            ]
        }
    }]
});
```

Of course gradient behaves in a different way. Highest point gets 0-stop color, lowest point gets 1-stop color. The same applies for a markers.